# ASP.NET Web API, Unwanted Quotes and Backslashes in Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

NET MVC Web API's, i created a class of Response so that All Routes return same response pattern,

```
[DataContract]
    public class Response
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int ResponseCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object ResponsePayload { get; set; }        
    }
```

I am calling APIResponse Method from All routes to return Response, Every time i would Pass Either DataTable or DataSet in object responseObj param of below function, I have to use ADO.NET DB Access layer, :)

```
private Object APIResponse(object responseObj, string _message = Constants.RESPONSE_MESSAGE_SUCCESS, int code = _RESPONSE_SUCCESS_CODE)
        {

            Response _response = new Response();
            _response.ResponsePayload = responseObj;
            _response.ResponseMessage = _message;
           _response.ResponseCode = code;

            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_response);
        }
```

if my responseObj param is of type DataSet, than i get Unwanted Quotes and Backslashes (Like in PHP if Magic Quotes are enable on Server) which produce a invalid JSON, 
Can you please help me in fixing this issue, to remove these slashes,

**Sample JSON:**

```
"{\"ResponseMessage\":\"Success\",\"ResponseCode\":200,\"ResponsePayload\":{\"StatusList\":[{\"StatusId\":1,\"Status\":\"To Be Dispatched\", ...........
```

Comment: In case of DataTable it create correct Json, only creating invalid Json in Case of DataSet,

Comment: Is that definitely the returned JSON and not just a Visual Studio debugger "quickview" representation of it? (Which will add the backslashes.)

Comment: This is JSON response that i can see in browser,

Comment: Why are you reinventing HTTP on top of HTTP?  HTTP already has HttpStatusCode and ReasonPhrase for this purpose.

Comment: @DarrelMiller , i tried HttpResponse but that did not works for me, i needed Json for My DataTable/DataSet, Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

you should define your Get like this

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(int id1)

public List<Response> Get( int id1)
```

instead of this

```
public string Get(int id1)
```